# How to reference similar named textboxes within a loop, with the loop iteration

Tags: vba, ms-access

There are 20 trainings, but different counties have different training requirements.  When looking at an employee on the form, **I want hide the training (text boxes) that they're not required to fulfill.**  The text boxes's names are uniformed [txtTrain#].  I had to resort to a Select/Case, because I don't know how to reference them with the loop counter.  The counter and the number at the end of each of their names are identical.

```
strCounty = Forms(frmEmpAll).txtCounty.Value

For i = 1 To 20
    yesNo = DLookup("Training" & i, "tblCountyTrain", _
        "County = '" & strCounty & "'")

    With Forms(frmEmpAll)

    Select Case i
        Case 1
            .txtTrain1.Visible = yesNo
        Case 2
            .txtTrain2.Visible = yesNo
        Case 3
            .txtTrain3.Visible = yesNo
```

… and so on.

This seems sloppy, and I want to clean my code.

Comment: `Forms(frmEmpAll)` has a `Controls` property that you'll want to look into. e.g. `.Controls("txtTrain" & i).Visible = yesNo`

Comment: Using Controls was the answer Mathieu.  Thank you.  It gave me the freedom to concatenate the controls name in VBA.